# Однозначный вызов перегруженной квалификатором volatile функции

Tags: c++, многопоточность, c++11, atomic, перегрузка-функций

Как вызвать определенную перегрузку функции на примере std::atomic?

```c++
struct MyStruct
{
    int a, b;
};

int main()
{
    cout << atomic<MyStruct>::is_lock_free();
}
```

Вот, на всякий случай, ругань визуалки[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как я понимаю, вы должны вызывать для определенного объекта, каковой объект уже сам - в силу своего объявления - укажет, что вызывать...

Типа

```
struct MyStruct
{
    int a, b;
};

atomic<MyStruct> a;
volatile atomic<MyStruct> b;

int main()
{
    cout << a.is_lock_free();
    cout << b.is_lock_free();
}
```

Впрочем, в этой области я вполне могу ошибаться...

Comment: Это сработает, но существует ли какая нибудь семантика уточнения, для вызова функции без создания объекта?

Comment: @SpaghettiMan `is_lock_free` вообще не может быть вызвана без создания объекта, это же не static функция. Квалификатор `const` или `const volatile` в этих перегрузках - это квалификатор объекта для которого она вызывается.